# In RShiny, change plot width / height for separate plots within same renderPlot()

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an RShiny app that includes 1 renderPlot call (in server) with its 1 corresponding plotOutput call (in ui). However, within the renderPlot code, there is a toggle from the ui that switches between two different plots. I would like the plots to have different coordinates. Below is a reproducible RShiny app using generic plots to highlight the aspects of my question:

```
selector = c("one", "two")
names(selector) = c("one", "two")

plot.width = 600
plot.height = 600

ui <- fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  # Organizes the title of the whole shiny app 
                  # ==========================================
                  column(width = 12, align = 'center',
                         h2('NBA Shot Chart and Movement Tracking Application'))
                ),

                fluidRow(
                  # This coordinates the location of the LHS widgets
                  # ================================================                 
                  column(width = 4, align = 'center', 
                           selectInput(inputId = 'shooter.input', label = 'Select Shooter:', multiple = FALSE, 
                                       choices = selector, selected = 'one')),

                  column(width = 8, align = 'left',
                         plotOutput('shot.chart', width = plot.width, height = plot.height)
                  )
                )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # renderPlot for the charts (shot charts and movement charts)
  output$shot.chart <- renderPlot({

    if(input$shooter.input == "one") {
      plot(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(6,7,8,9,10))
    }
    else {
      plot(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,1,1,1,1))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Okay, my question has to do with the plot.width and plot.height parameters set in plotOutput in ui. I want these parameters to change for each of the two plots. When selectInput is set == "one", I want the parameters to be 600 and 600, and when the selectInput is set == "two", I want the parameters to be 600 and 800.

Has anybody run into this problem before, and knows how to deal with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
library(shiny)

selector = c("one", "two")
names(selector) = c("one", "two")


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    # Organizes the title of the whole shiny app 
    # ==========================================
    column(width = 12, align = 'center',
           h2('NBA Shot Chart and Movement Tracking Application'))
  ),

  fluidRow(
    # This coordinates the location of the LHS widgets
    # ================================================                 
    column(width = 4, align = 'center', 
           selectInput(inputId = 'shooter.input', label = 'Select Shooter:', multiple = FALSE, 
                       choices = selector, selected = 'one')),

    column(width = 8, align = 'left',
           uiOutput('shot.chart_ui')
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$shot.chart_ui <- renderUI({
    if(input$shooter.input == "one") {
      plot.width = 600
      plot.height = 600
    }else{
      plot.width = 600
      plot.height = 800
    }
    plotOutput('shot.chart', width = plot.width, height = plot.height)

  })
  # renderPlot for the charts (shot charts and movement charts)
  output$shot.chart <- renderPlot({

    if(input$shooter.input == "one") {
      plot(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(6,7,8,9,10))
    }
    else {
      plot(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,1,1,1,1))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have moved the `plotOutput` to the `server` and furthermore i have put `plot.width` and `plot.height` into reactive context.