# In RShiny, using actionButton values within conditionalPanel causing many headaches

Tags: r, shiny

I have spent the last half hour reading about conditionalPanel, as well as actionButtons and how their value increments by 1 each time the button is pressed. With that said, here's what I'm trying to do below and what problem I am facing:

**The problem**
I am using conditionalPanel to toggle between two different renderPlots. The reason I am using two different renderPlots, rather than both plots within the same renderPlot, is because it is important that the two plots have different height / width dimensions. I am using the actionButton's value within the conditionalPanel, which IS BAD.

**What I want**
I want movement.chart to be displaying if togglemovement actionButton was more recently pressed of the 2 buttons. I want shot.chart to be displaying if toggleshotchart was more recently pressed.

**What I wish I could do**
If I could only use plotData$value within the conditional, I would be all set. plotData$value is being used to enter if statements in the renderPlots to determine which plots should be plotted, but I can't use them in conditionalPanel.

With all of that said, here's a shortened version of my project.

```
library(shiny)

# 2. UI layout
# ============
ui <- fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 4, align = 'center', 
              actionButton(inputId = 'toggleshotchart', label = 'Launch Shots'), 
              actionButton(inputId = 'togglemovement', label = 'Launch Movements')
          ),

          # This displays either the shot or movement chart
          # ===============================================
          column(width = 8, align = 'left',
                 conditionalPanel("input.togglemovement > input.toggleshotchart",
                                  plotOutput('movement.chart', height = 650, width = 1128)
                 ),
                 conditionalPanel("input.togglemovement <= input.toggleshotchart",
                                  plotOutput('shot.chart', height = 846, width = 900)
                 )
          )
        )
)

# 3. Server Layout
# ================
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Create some reactive stuff to toggle charts
  plotData <- reactiveValues(value = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$toggleshotchart, {
    plotData$value <- 0
  })

  observeEvent(input$togglemovement, {
    plotData$value <- 1
  })

  # create the first chart
  output$shot.chart <- renderPlot({

    # this chart is displayed at launch
    if (is.null(plotData$value)) {
      plot(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,2,3,4,5))
    }

    # this chart SHOULD BE displayed after clicking toggleshotchart
    else if(plotData$value == 0) {
      hist(rnorm(10))
    }      

    # Do nothing (prev displayed motion chart here)
    else {
      # do nothing
    }
  })

  # this chart SHOULD BE displayed after clicking togglemovementchart
  output$movement.chart <- renderPlot({
    if(plotData$value == 1) {
      hist(c(1,2,3,2,1))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I read a lot about resetting the actionButton's value, but couldn't find anything that would fix my problem. It seems like resetting actionButton values to 0 is not easy / cannot be done. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated on this task of mine!

EDIT - I asked this related question earlier - [In RShiny, change plot width / height for separate plots within same renderPlot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894712/in-rshiny-change-plot-width-height-for-separate-plots-within-same-renderplot) - where the solution works, but is for a slightly different question. The more I worked on this issue, the more I realized that my initial question did not address my actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `radioButtons` to toggle between two plots?

```
library(shiny)

# 2. UI layout
# ============
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, 
           radioButtons("choice_plot","Launch",choices=list("Shots","Movements"), selected="Shots")),

    # This displays either the shot or movement chart
    # ===============================================
    column(width = 8, align = 'left', uiOutput("plot_ui"))
  )
)

# 3. Server Layout
# ================
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot_ui <- renderUI({
    if(input$choice_plot == 'Shots') {
      plot.width = 1128
      plot.height = 650
    }else{
      plot.width = 900
      plot.height = 846
    }
    plotOutput('plot', width = plot.width, height = plot.height)

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$choice_plot == 'Shots'){
      hist(rnorm(10))
    }else{
      hist(c(1,2,3,2,1))
      }
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is as well my try with `actionButton`:

```
library(shiny)

# 2. UI layout
# ============
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, 
           actionButton("button1", "Shots"),
           actionButton("button2", "Movements")),

    # This displays either the shot or movement chart
    # ===============================================
    column(width = 8, align = 'left', uiOutput("plot_ui"))
  )
)

# 3. Server Layout
# ================
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot_ui <- renderUI({
    if(input$button1 == 1) {
      plot.width = 1128
      plot.height = 650
    }else{
      plot.width = 900
      plot.height = 846
    }
    plotOutput('plot', width = plot.width, height = plot.height)

  })

  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    v$data <- rnorm(10)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    v$data <- c(1,2,3,2,1)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$data)) return()
    hist(v$data)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: HI Malvina, thanks for your comments both on this as well as my other post. In my complete app, there are several selectInput toggles as well which change the features of each plot.

The action buttons are clicked after the selectInput toggles are changed in order to update the charts, which is why I would strongly prefer to keep the action buttons over radio buttons.

Comment: If I cannot get the action button to work as desired, then this would be a decent alternative I guess.

Comment: Could You explain more about it?

Comment: I have tried to solve Your problem using `actionButton` only, have a look at the answer